# Where can I find all ruby classes(data types)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, class, ruby-on-rails-4

I just found out I can store a date(e.i. birthday, calendar date, etc) under the date class in my database(t.date :date_of_birth). Where can I find all the different kinds of classes I can store data under(I only know string, integer, boolean, text & now date)? I've searched and haven't found a comprehensive list that includes the date class.

Answer (score 0):

`:primary_key`, `:string`, `:text`, `:integer`, `:float`, `:decimal`, `:datetime`, `:timestamp`, `:time`, `:date`, `:binary`, `:boolean`.

I think [there is also a complete list of them](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column).